# sorting images into gridview using date

Tags: android

I'm using the following code ,it picks image from gallery and displays image in random order

```
String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
        imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,null, orderBy);
        int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
```

I want the images to get sorted via date it has been taken(Eg:Latest ones first and oldest photos later)...

and one more problem that when i use above code it only loads images in DCIM folder ,i want all the images from phone also.......

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `orderBy` to

```
String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC";
```

Comment: but one more thing i want all the images from my phone but only images from DCIM folder gets loaded..

Comment: but this is a different question. changing questions after accepting an answer is really impolite. you should create a new question for your new question.

Comment: The MediaStore can give you only the images it knows of. If you want it to show images from diferent folders you must make it to scan these folders: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12190181/2331953